# React-native app not auto starting on boot

Tags: android, react-native

I want to load my app after the phone reboots. For this I am using this in manifest file:

```
    <receiver android:name="com.app.BootReceiver" android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

and I have BootReceiver Class which is :

```
    package com.app;

    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;

    public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
           myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
           context.startActivity(myIntent);
       }
    }
```

It works when I run my application on an attached device with  npx react-native run-android command.
But when I create a release build APK to test it on a device it doesn't work. On the same device if I attach it to computer and install the app using react-native run-android, app automatically gets started after phone restart

What am I missing here??

I want to reload my app automatically if it was already running in the background after the phone reboots